# onClick event handler called on load as opposed to on click

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I'm new to React and have come across an issue when trying to trigger a function that has been set as a prop. Here is my component:

```
class SamplesInnerLrg extends Component {  
    playSampleAction(sample,sampleId) {
       console.log(sample);
    }
    render() {
         return <div className="samples-container-inner-styling">
   {

     this.props.loadAllInitSamples.map((sample) => {
        return (
                <div key={sample.id} className="sample-comp-lge">
                <div className="sample-comp-lge-head-wrap">
                    <div className="sample-comp-lge-audio" id={sample.id} ref={sample.id} onClick={this.playSampleAction(sample,sample.id)}>
                        <audio preload="auto" className="audioTag">
                              <source src={sample.soundSource} type="audio/wav" />
                        </audio>
                    </div>
                    <div className="sample-comp-lge-header">
                        <span className="sample-comp-lge-Name"><h1>{sample.sampleName}</h1></span>
                        <span className="sample-comp-lge-id"><h2><a href="#">{sample.sampleFamily}</a></h2></span>
                        <div className="sample-comp-lge-owner-cont">
                            <div className="sample-comp-lge-owner-inner">
                                <a href="">{sample.uploader}</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className="sample-comp-lge-bottom-wrap">
                    <div className="sample-comp-lge-tags-cont">
                        <div className="sample-comp-lge-tag">
                            <ul className="sample-tags-list">
                                {
                                    sample.tags.map((tag) => {
                                        return ( 

                                            <li key={tag}><a href="#">#{tag}</a></li>
                                        )
                                    })

                                }
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                </div>
            )
        })
   }
   </div>
    }
}
```

The event I'm trying to trigger is `playSampleAction` . The event seems to fire when I load the page but not when I click. I tried adding `.bind(this)` at the end of the `onClick` but sill doesn't do the click action. Worth noting there are no console errors when I click.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You invoke the function immediately and pass `onClick` the return value, which makes it seem to run on load. You must pass a *reference* of the function, not invocation:

```
onClick={this.playSampleAction.bind(undefined, sample, sample.id)}
```

What this does is use [`Function.prototype.bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) which binds the `this` context and other arguments, returning a new callable function with those arguments applied. From the documentation:

> The `bind()` method creates a new function that, when called, has its this keyword set to the provided value, with a given sequence of arguments preceding any provided when the new function is called.

In the code above I pass `undefined` for `this` , and the function arguments. Thus, the function will not be immediately *invoked*, but the a function will be passed to the `onClick` event instead of an invocation which would pass the return value.

**Note**: if that's the only place where you're going to use `playSampleAction`, bind it in the class constructor, to avoid creating a new function ever time on click.

---

Another (in my opinion, preferred) solution is to use [ES6 arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions):

```
onClick={() => this.playSampleAction(sample, sample.id)}
```

You can then add whatever parameters you need. Because the arrow function is just shorter syntax for an anonymous function, a callable function is passed - not an invocation. This will correctly execute on click.

Answer (score 0):

`playSampleAction` must return a function to have it trigger on click:

```
playSampleAction(sample,sampleId) {
   return function(event){
      console.log(sample);
   }
}
```

React props are evaluated at rendering. As a result, every functions called in a prop, like `onClick`, will be triggered. What you want is to givea callback to `onClick` to havvev it triggered on click only. So `playSampleAction` must return a function